# Change Logback property value from within Java main

Tags: java, logback

I think I am close. Using Logback in my Java app

In my logback.xml file I have

```
<property name="WorkStationID" value="B0094882" />
```

Now I'm trying to change to set that value from the main thread like so

```
try {
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        JoranConfigurator jc = new JoranConfigurator();
        jc.setContext(context);
        context.reset();
        context.putProperty("WorkStationID", "GotIt");
        jc.doConfigure("/Users/logback.xml");
    } catch (JoranException ex) {
        logger.error("init logging failed", ex);
    }
```

But despite having it in my pattern

```
<pattern>%msg ${WorkStationID:-A000000} %n</pattern>
```

It always logs `B0094882` and not `GotIt`

I think I am close but i'm just not getting the property reset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the property defined in the configuration file (local scope) is taking precedence over the property defined in the context scope. Follow [this](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution) documentation link.

> A property can be defined for insertion in local scope, in context
>   scope, or in system scope. Local scope is the default. Although it is
>   possible to read variables from the OS environment, it is not possible
>   to write into the OS environment.
>
> LOCAL SCOPE A property with local scope exists from the point of its
>   definition in a configuration file until the end of
>   interpretation/execution of said configuration file. As a corollary,
>   each time a configuration file is parsed and executed, variables in
>   local scope are defined anew.
>
> CONTEXT SCOPE A property with context scope is inserted into the
>   context and lasts as long as the context or until it is cleared. Once
>   defined, a property in context scope is part of the context. As such,
>   it is available in all logging events, including those sent to remote
>   hosts via serialization.
>
> SYSTEM SCOPE A property with system scope is inserted into the JVM's
>   system properties and lasts as long as the JVM or until it is cleared.
>
> Properties are looked up in the the local scope first, in the context
>   scope second, in the system properties scope third, and in the OS
>   environment last. During substitution, properties are looked up in the
>   local scope first, in the context scope second, in the system
>   properties scope third, and in the OS environment fourth and last.

As a [workaround](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-239) you could do add this in the logback.xml

```
<if condition='isNull("aProperty")'>
<then><property name="aProperty" value="aValue" /></then>
</if>
```

If the aProperty system property is not defined, then aProperty will be defined in local scope with the value of your choice.